# Hero Quest - Adaptation to remove 'Evil Wizard'

Tags: house-rules

I'm just wondering if anyone has come across an adaptation to the rules of Hero Quest for a version where you don't need an evil wizard? I'm wanting to try and play 2 player co-operative games and almost have a more random monster appearance like Warhammer Quest etc, but not quite sure if it'll work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boy do I love Hero Quest -- that's the game that started it all for me.

I've tried playing Hero Quest without Zargon a couple of times, and it's tricky but doable.

You basically need one person playing both a hero and Zargon, and trying to move the monsters as impartially as possible.  For example, if you enter a room with two Fimir, and its their turn to act, don't have them run off afraid, or have them move up and then not attack.  Either the hero/Zargon, or the entire group, need to come up with what you think the monsters would do.

You can either come up with a strict attack order (monsters will go for the Wizard first, Elf second for example) or dice off to see which way the monster will go.

You might have to re-write or re-copy the scenarios with the treasure notes and secret doors and traps written down elsewhere, so you can't cheat and say "Well this treasure chest is trapped because I read it right here" or "Hey, there's a secret door here, I just read about it".  Alternately you can put the traps and secret doors on the board, but you need to roll some target value to even be aware that it's there.

There's a site called [BowserBag.com](http://www.bowserbag.com/heroquest/) that has some interesting links, including a PDF for play without Zargon, found [here](http://www.bowserbag.com/heroquest/Hero%20Quest%20Rules.PDF).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Doesn't really detail much about playing without Zargon but some of the other rules are interesting. I'm liking the idea of copying down the instructions without revealing secrets, or even creating a number/room map and coming up with some cards to determine which room you enter randomly each time you play.

Comment: I asked this ages ago, before I got into D&D. Interestingly the D&D games like the CastleRavenloft board game have a mechanic where monsters generally move towards the nearest creature, on the turn of the person who revealed it. It is completely random however, the map and the monsters revealed based on icons that are on the tiles.